# Compactness, pseudocompactness, and realcompactness without Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, compactness, realcompact-spaces

A space is [compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000016) provided every open cover admits a finite subcover.

A space is [pseduocompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000022) provided every continuous image of the space into the Euclidean line $\mathbb R$ is bounded.

A space is [realcompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realcompact_space) provided it embeds as a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$.

We can quickly see that every pseudocompact+realcompact space is compact: take the space $H\subseteq \mathbb R^\kappa$ (by realcompactness); its projection $H_\alpha\subseteq\mathbb R$ for each factor $\alpha<\kappa$ must be bounded (by psuedocompactness), and thus $\overline{H_\alpha}$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem. This makes $H$ a closed subset of the compact space $\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}\overline{H_\alpha}$, and thus compact.

It's immediate that every compact space is pseudocompact. It's also true that every compact Hausdorff space is realcompact.

So we have a cute characterization for Hausdorff spaces: *A Hausdorff space is compact if and only if it is both pseudocompact and realcompact.*

My question is this: is there a natural property $R$ that implies neither Hausdorff nor pseudocompact, such that an arbitrary space is compact if and only if it is both pseudocompact and $R$?

Comment: For arbitrary spaces, pseudocompactness tells you very little about compactness, since there might just not be any nonconstant functions to $\mathbb{R}$ at all.

Comment: The projections maps $\Bbb R^{\kappa}\to\Bbb R$ are not closed maps in general. What makes you say $H_\alpha$ must be closed?

Comment: @FShrike I agree, instead the proof should be as follows, each $H_\alpha$ is bounded, so $H$ is a closed subspace of compact space $\prod_{\alpha < \kappa} \overline{H_\alpha}$, hence compact.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, will edit appropriately when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article *"Supports of continuous functions"* by M. Mandelker, the following definition of realcompactness and results are given:

**Definition 1.** A family $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ of subsets of topological space $X$ is called *stable* if every $f\in C(X)$ is bounded on some $A\in\mathcal{F}$.

**Definition 2.** $X$ is *realcompact* if every stable family of closed subsets with finite intersection property has non-empty intersection.

This agrees with standard definition of realcompactess (theorem 5.1):

**Theorem 1.** If $X$ is $T_{3.5}$, then $X$ is realcompact iff there is cardinal $\kappa$ such that $X$ embedds as closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\kappa$.

Moreover, it's exactly what we need (theorem 5.2):

**Theorem 2.** $X$ is compact iff $X$ is pseudocompact and realcompact.

Comment: do you have a url for the article?

Comment: @PatrickR https://doi.org/10.2307/1995598